# Self loop on CityData graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, curated-data

Why does  `NearestNeighborGraph[ CityData[{Large, "Colorado", "UnitedStates"}], 3, DistanceFunction -> GeoDistance, DirectedEdges -> False, VertexLabels -> "Name"]` create a self loop on the graph? Is there a way to get rid of it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoDistance is computing minimal distances between the polygons of the cities, and some cities are contiguous, i.e. their polygons are touching, so the result is zero. See the non-diagonal zeros in

```
TableForm[GeoDistance[cities, cities], TableHeadings -> {cities, cities}]
```

You can compute distances among centered points instead of polygons using this alternative distance function:

```
DistanceFunction -> Function[GeoDistance[GeoPosition[#1], GeoPosition[#2]]]
```

Then this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @jose!

Comment: Why does `WeatherData[{"Buckeye", "Arizona",  "UnitedStates"}, "Temperature", "NonMetricValue"]` this fail? @jose I am trying to create a city graph with weather data as feature.

Comment: WeatherData is based on weather stations. In a case like this you can first find the nearest station and then check its temperature. Something like: WeatherData[
 WeatherData[{"Buckeye", "Arizona", "UnitedStates"}], "Temperature", "NonMetricValue"]. This should have worked automatically.

Comment: For bunch of US Cities, I am getting `Missing["NotAvailable"]`   for example `WeatherData[WeatherData["Miami"], "Temperature", "NonMetricValue"]`..why is that so? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Actually this `WeatherData["Miami", "Temperature", "NonMetricValue"]` works instead of `WeatherData[WeatherData["Miami"], "Temperature", "NonMetricValue"]`

Comment: But again for certain case like this one `WeatherData[
 Entity["City", {"WatfordCity", "NorthDakota", 
   "UnitedStates"}], "Temperature", "NonMetricValue"]` it does not work? Is there a universal fix for these issues?